# Can't access firebase values in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to access a child node value in firebase and shows nothing on console.log??

My code is:
My constructor is something like this:

```
this.state = {
      Hemo:'',
}
ComponentDidMount(){
db
    .ref('VitalSigns/'+this.props.uName)
    .on('value', snapshot=> {
      this.setState({
        Hemo: snapshot.val().Hemoglobin
      });
    });
    console.log(this.state.Hemo);
}
```

And My firebase database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPdr.png)

Comment: State is set asynchronously so never assume that logging afterwards will return the expected state values. It takes a callback -> `this.setState({Hemo: snapshot.val().Hemoglobin}, () => console.log(this.state.Hemo))`

Comment: the casing of `componentDidMount` matters too

Comment: I tried both as mentioned in comments but nothing changes.....

Comment: have you confirmed `this.props.uName` and `snapshot.val()` are as expected?